# Re - compose MapView when mapId changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following [this](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Crane/app/src/main/java/androidx/compose/samples/crane/details/MapViewUtils.kt) example for creating composable Google `MapView`. So far everything works great except the [cloud-based styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-based-map-styling#add-map-id). After I change the dark/light theme via `LiveData`, everything get's recomposed accordingly, except the map.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Composable
fun rememberMapViewWithLifecycle(): MapView {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val darkTheme = Global.viewModel.theme.observeAsState()
    val mapView = remember { MapView(context, GoogleMapOptions().mapId(if (darkTheme.value == "Dark") DARK_CLOUD_THEME_ID else LIGHT_CLOUD_THEME_ID)).apply {
            id = R.id.map
        }
    }

    // Makes MapView follow the lifecycle of this composable
    val lifecycleObserver = rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView)
    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    DisposableEffect(lifecycle) {
        lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
        }
    }

    return mapView
}
```

What can I do to update the Google Map styling? My first thought was about force-recompose, but it seems this is not possible as compose engine takes care of this. I would like to avoid going back to `.json` map formatting if possible.

Comment: Global.viewModel? is it a static variable? You should not be using static variables this way, it's unlikely that it'll work after Android lifecycle things happen

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It was just a trial & error thing. I've updated the rememberMapViewWithLifecycle function to receive darkTheme boolean parameter, but it doesn't reflect on the map styling.